# Firestore security rules: get() use in hasAny() list method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I was wondering if this security rule would be possible:

```
function productForUser() {
        return resource.data.products.hasAny(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.products);
    }
```

When I try to test it in the testing plaground on the Firebase website, it is sucessful. However, when I try to run it with Javascript, with this query, I get the read denied, with "missing or insufficient permissions":

`query.where("products", "array-contains", productId);`

I can confirm that the user has the array of products, containg the specific product that is being looked up in the query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule works in the console simulator because the simulator only supports "get" type requests for a single document.  It doesn't work for queries because [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  The rule will not be evaluated for each and every document in the collection, as that would not scale well at all for very large collections.  To specify conditions for queries, you will need to provide exact values to check from the client - you will not be able to use a get() to find other values.

If you want to test queries before publishing your rules, you should not be using the simulator, and instead use the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) to test code that actually performs a query.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any recommendation for writing the security rules for what I am doing? I'm rather stuck on solving this issue, it would be nice to keep a where clause, and I can't provide two "array-contains" clauses, as that is not supported. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: The only way to make rules work for a query is if all of the data required for determining the permission is contained in the query itself.  This means you will probably have to restructure your data and duplicate some data into "products" documents.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I've tried doing this, the other data that I want to verify is actually also in an array in the document (being the userId), but I cannot use it as I cannot query with two `array-contains`. I've tried combining the `array-contains` with an `in` query, as it is only one string element in the array that I need to compare. This also gives me the same error, even after adding the security rule to check if the userId is in the array, which it is. Is there any other way that I can restrutcture the query to get it to work? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't know, without seeing your actual data and queries.  Please post another question with specific details that anyone can use the reproduce the issue.