# Querying with two array with firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I currently have two arrays in a single document, one representing product ids and the other representing user ids. In my query, I need to query both of the arrays for firestore security rules to work correctly, but to do that, I tried using `array-contains` and `in` in the same query, which is acceptable in the documentation, but when I go to query, I get "missing or insufficient permissions".

```
db.collection('Depots')
  .where("products", "array-contains", productId)
  .where("users", "in", "lk9asdn340fk3fvb")
  .get();
```

This is my security rule:

```
function uidAndProductInDocument() {
    return request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
}
```

This is what the contents of the document looks like:

[image]

However, even this security rule fails and does not return anything, even though there are docs in the database that should be returned, as they match the parameters.

I'm not sure how to secure the product relationship, as that relation for the product-user is in another document, and I have tried another approach in my other question, which can be found here:
[Firestore security rules: get() use in hasAny() list method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891502/firestore-security-rules-get-use-in-hasany-list-method)

Is there anything that I am missing or need to do for this query to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact data in use here.  Show us 1) the contents of the document, 2) the full query, and 3) that you're sure a user is signed in.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the question for you - I'm certainly sure that the user is logged in for this query, as logging the `idToken.claims` results in the claims being outputted. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Those values in `users` don't look like Firebase Auth UIDs.  Also, we can't see what's in `idToken.claims.user_id`.  Please edit the question to show all the relevant data, hardcoding values as required, so we can see all the data in play.  I've never seen anyone try to use anything but `auth.currentUser.uid` to specify a UID in a query.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've hardcoded the value into the query, which still doesn't work (I changed the actual firebase uids for this question)

Comment: The value you're passing to the query isn't actually a Firebase Auth user ID, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to `request.auth.uid` in rules.  Actual user IDs are much longer than that.  I don't know what that value actually represents or where it comes from, so I don't have any advice on how to proceed.  Perhaps you could edit the quesiton to show how you populated that data and what you expect the rule should actually check.

Comment: @DougStevenson the value isn't actually the real value - I replaced it as I wasn't sure if the uid is sensitive. I'm getting it from the idToken and it is the right value - the firebase uid is the same as in the document.

Comment: The UID is not sensitive.  They can't be faked.  Without seeing actual values, and specific code that verifies that the values are all exactly as you expect, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Also I think you second where clause is incorrect.  You should be doing an array-contains filter.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your help. I can't use another array-contains filter on it as firestore only supports one array-contains. Is there anything else that I can use to support two array where queries? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider restructuring your data in order to support the query you need.  Since Firestore can't perform two array-contains queries, one of your arrays should be converted to an object, where the keys are values of the array, and the field value is simply `true`.  For example, you could take your users list and make it look like this for each user:

```
users: {
  xxxx: true
  yyyy: true
}
```

Now you can query like this:

```
db.collection('Depots')
  .where("products", "array-contains", productId)
  .where(`users.${uid}`, "==", true)
  .get();
```

And your rule can check like this:

```
return resource.data.users[request.auth.uid]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out a way of doing this for a long time. Is there any chance that support for multiple array-contains clauses in the same query in the future? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: No idea. You can always file a feature request with Firebase support.

Comment: How would indexing work with this? When I go to create the index for this, it asks me to create a specifc index for the `users.<firebase_id>`, will this work throughout all of the entries? Thanks again for your help

Comment: I don't think it will.  You might have to convert products to also not use an array.

Comment: When I do this, it makes me index the user. Indexing `users.abc123myid` `ascending`. I can't index for each user. Does anyone know why I must index but this example must not.