# Querying for object key in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I currently have a few issues with my Firestore querying technique. As per this stackoverflow post I made recently, [Querying with two array with firestore security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893331/querying-with-two-array-with-firestore-security-rules)

The answer proposed to add the the "ids" into a object, with the key as the id, and the value simply being "true". I have completed this, and now my structure looks like so:

[image]

This leaves me with this query:

```
db.collection('Depots')
  .where(`products.${productId}`, '==', true)
  .where(`users.${userId}`, '==', true)
  .where('created', '>', 1585998560500)
  .orderBy('created', 'asc')
  .get();
```

This query leaves me with throwing an error, asking to create an index:

> The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...

However, this tries to index the specific object key, i.e. `QXooVYGBIFWKo6C` so `products.QXooVYGBIFWKo6C`. Which is certianly not what I want, as this query changes, and can have an infinite number of possibilities, which means I would have to create another index for each key entry in order to query it.

Is there any way to solve this issue? I am assuming it needs to index this query due to the different operators used in the query, so I was wondering if there were any workarounds to this issue.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I unfortunately can't see how this structure would be flattened into a single index. What is the purpose of "users"? If you can flip it into "user0 = someId" and "user1 = someOtherId", you might have to make two queries but you can keep the array-contains for the products key (you will use one query for `where('user0', '==', userId)` and the other `where('user1', '==', userId)` and then merge the results on the client).

Comment: @samthecodingman I feel like that is kind of messy - I don't know how many users there will be per document, and so I don't want to hard code the keys to a specific amount of users per item.

Comment: I know it's messy - my point was to demonstrate how it can't be flattened into a single index. The example I gave, flattened it into only two indexes.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve/query? What are the ideal query cases? I don't know how there can be so many answers already and nobody has even asked you this question.

Comment: @bsod There is other data in the document that is needed in the program for when I query - I removed it as it wasn't helpful for the question and the two maps did not fit on the window for me to take a screenshot.

Comment: What I mean is, overall, what are you ultimately trying to query for? What is the dream scenario? Trying to avoid an XY problem if there is one.

Comment: @bsod I am trying to query to get a document where the two values: a `productId` and a `userId` specfically match those inside a document. There can be multiple `productId`s as well as `userId`s inside a document. Originally I tried to put them both in an array, but firestore cannot handle two `array-contains` clauses in one query, hence trying this. I am stuck with this as firestore tries to index the fields due to different operators in the query, which does not allow me to query the map, as it creates an index of specifically a certain key. I hope that I understood correctly.

Comment: I totally understand all of that. Btw, I've seen that recommendation (to make the identifier the field name and a boolean the field value) a lot here and I've commented numerous times that it's a poor model because it destroys the index. My question is a bigger picture one. Forget Firestore and documents for a moment; what is it the user is trying to achieve? Are we dealing with factories that have products and you're trying to locate user orders? Because of how NoSQL works overall, and Firestore specifically, make sure you first have the right architecture first.

Comment: @bsod Kind of - A depot can have "products" and "workers" (users). They are immutable for as long as the "Depot" exists. I added them to an array as (I thought) this was easy to query - "where a user is in the same Depot as a product is" is the query I want to achieve, would you need me to describe anything else? Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: Are you trying to find users, depots, or products? If a user is in a depot with a product, couldn't you just find the depots with that product and then see which users are in that depot? Is there one specific query you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @bsod There is extra data in the document, that I have not included here which is in the document, that I would like to find by both the products and users.

Comment: Your request is still confusing. It appears, by your code, that you want to find the specific depots where specific users match specific products. But can't a user only be in one depot? Do you want to find all users that have access to `productXYZ` or all depots that have `productXYZ`? Your example query appears to want to get all depots where `userXYZ` is true and `productXYZ` is true. But can't that only be one depot?  Why not just find the depot `userXYZ` is in and see if that depot contains that product?

Comment: @bsod ```Why not just find the depot `userXYZ` is in and see if that depot contains that product? ``` I could, but due to lots of depots, where one user can be in many depots, the product may also not be in the depot as well. (one product can be in many depots as well). Specifically, this is a filter method and could be the case that someone would try to find the `userId` alongside the `productId`. As you said, `I want to get all depots where userXYZ is true and productXYZ is true`. Is there anyway I can structure the database to support this query? Many thanks for your continued help.

Comment: But can one user be in many depots at the same time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210542/discussion-between-bsod-and-danwillm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion in chat, this is the starting point I would suggest. Who knows what the end architecture would look like, but I think this or very close to this. You say that a user can exist in multiple depots at the same time and multiple depots can contain the same products, also at the same time. You also said that a depot can never have more than 40 users at a given time, so an array of 40 users would certainly not encroach on Firestore's document limit of `1,048,576` bytes.

```
[collection]
    <documentId>
        - field: value

[depots]

    <UUID>
        - depotId: string       "depot456"
        - productCount: num     5,000

    <UUID>
        - depotId: string       "depot789"
        - productCount: num     4,500


[products]

    <UUID>
        - productId: string     "lotion123"
        - depotId: string       "depot456"
        - users: [string]       ["user10", "user27", "user33"]

    <UUID>
        - productId: string     "lotion123"
        - depotId: string       "depot789"
        - users: [string]       ["user10", "user17", "user50"]


[users]

    <userId>
        - depots: [string]      ["depot456", "depot999"]

    <userId>
        - depots: [string]      ["depot333", "depot999"]
```

In NoSQL, storage is cheap and computation isn't so denormalize your data as much as you need to make your queries possible and efficient (fast and cheap).

To find all depots in a single query where `user10` and `lotion123` are both true, query the products collection where `productId` equals `x` and `users` array-contains `y` and collect the `depotId` values from those results. If you want to preserve the array-contains operation for something else, you'd have to denormalize your data further (replace the array for a single user). Or you could split this query into two separate queries.

With this model, when a user leaves a depot, get all products where `users` array-contains that user and remove that `userId` from the array. And when a user joins a depot, get all products where `depotId` equals `x` and append that `userId` to the array.

Watch this video, and others by Rick, to get a solid handle on NoSQL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this looks like exactly what I need! Thanks again for the continued help.

Comment: Watch that video! It will really help you.

Comment: Will do! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

What you have here is a map field, for which indexes should usually be created [automatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing).

That indeed means that you'll have as many indexes as you have products, which means:

1. You are limited in how many products you can have, as there is a [maximum of 40,000 index entries per document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits).
2. You pay more per document, as you pay for the storage of each index.

If these are not what you want, you'll have to switch back to your original model, with the query limitations you had there. There doesn't seem to be a solution that fits both of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried the query without the different operators in it (removing the ">" and "orderBy" and it does indeed work with that query without having to make a separate index. Is there any workaround for the current structure? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@danwillm If you are not sure about the number of users and products then your DB structure seems unfit for this situation because there are size and length limitations of the firestore document.
 You should rather create a separate collection for products and users i.e normalize your data and have a reference for the user in the product collection.

```
User : 
       {
          userId: documentId,
          name: John,
          ...otherInfo
       }

Product : 

       {
          productId: documentId,
          createdBy: userId,
          createdOn:date,
          productName:"exa",
          ...otherInfo
       }
```

This way you there will be the size of the document would be limited, i.e try avoiding using maps/arrays in firestore if you are not sure about there size.
Also, in this case, the number of queries would be increased but you don't need many indexes in this case.